# WCF Test client and multiple binding (http, tcp etc)

Tags: wcf

suppose i have developed a wcf service application where svc file is created and i i have two binding for the same service like

```
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:12659/CalculatorService"
                          binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding"
                contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator"/>
                <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:12659/CalculatorService/mex"
                          binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>


                <endpoint address="http://localhost:12659/CalculatorService"
                          binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyTcpActivation.ICalculator" />
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:12659/CalculatorService/mex"
                          binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

when i run the service from VS2010 IDE then wcf test client run. if i off all the endpoint related to tcp then wcf test client can run my service properly but if i have two endpoing like tcp, http or only tcp then i saw wcf test client throw error wcf failed to add a service. service metadata may not be accessible

so i like to know that wcf test client can not handle tcp bidning ? if it can handle tcp binding then tell me why i am getting that error? please guide. thanks

Answer (score 1):

try using different port for tcp and http.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/650869/Creating-a-Self-Hosted-WCF-Service

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Generally speaking Stack Overflow does not consider link only answers acceptable. Please provide specific details to answer the question.